# Not Included in list Error - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So, i have en and es as supported locales in my application.. the default locale is en.
when i try to change the locale in console and save the object, i get an error saying that 
locale is not included in list... but while validating locale, i have included the :inclusion attribute.. it refers to the file where the locale is stored...any idea as to what the error might be?

i tried changing the locale in the gui.. it works. if i can change it in the gui, i should be able to do the same in rails console as well... all the articles that i saw for "not included in list" led me only to the :include attribute and whatever i try, even if i give it as

```
:inclusion { :in => %(en es) }
```

it gives the same error :|

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong syntax for hash. try

```
validates :my_field, :inclusion => { :in => %w(en es) }
```

I actually prefer `%w[en es]` over the parenthesis. But both is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 :inclusion { :in => %w(en es) }
```

**(notice the `w` !)**

Comment: still the same...but i should give the constants like locale in a different file and import it na?? that's the good practice right?

Comment: i made a temp fix for that by referring directly to constant file... if i give it directly, it shows me the same error... any idea as to why this is happening?